# Interface with Optional method

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

I have an IMessage interface that I created. It's being used to make sure all messages have a Header, and Body. I am coming across an issue, where one message doesn't have a Header, but it needs the interface.

I have 3 options:

1. Use optional where we always return an empty optional, for this one implementation of getHeader()
2. Throw an exception, which will need to be caught to continue
3. Return an empty array for the header

Am I correct to use option 1?

I have simplified my program, and normally getHeader, getBody, and getFull return some type of array. The question is what to do about getHeader because one message does not have a header.

```
struct IMessage
{
    virtual int getHeader() = 0;
    virtual int getBody() = 0;
    virtual int getFull() = 0;
};

class Message1 : public IMessage
{
    int header;
    int body;
    int full;

    public:
    int getHeader() { return header;}
    int getBody() { return body;}
    int getFull() { return full;}
};

class Message2 : public IMessage
{
    int body;
    int full;

    public:
    int getHeader() { //Optional or exception }            //I don't have a header
    int getBody() { return body; }
    int getFull() { return full; }
};
```

Comment: Sure I can do that

Comment: IMO this is so trivial I would just return empty array.

Answer (score 3):

If the purpose of the interface is to represent messages with a header and a body, then why does a message without a header "need" the interface?

Instead, perhaps you ought to have two interfaces. One represents all messages, with the only requirement being a body. Another extends that interface with the requirement to have a header as well. Then use whichever is appropriate.

Alternatively, consider a missing header to actually be an existent but empty header. This is your option 3.

Comment: This is too idealistic. Though the given information is not enough, adding a new inheritance for a trivial difference like missing header sounds not a good idea. Maybe add a method `has_head()` will just be fine. Then `get_head()` can legally throw an exception.

Comment: @liliscent: The difference between an interface that is designed to properly reflect the thing it is supposed to represent, and an interface that is not, is hardly "trivial". That being said, again yes it may well be that option 3 is the best way to fix that problem.

Answer (score 2):

> I have an IMessage interface that I created. It's being used to make sure all messages have a Header, and Body.

If that is actually the job of an `IMessage` then your new thing is not an `IMessage`.

Of course, types like `IMessage` are often bad ideas exactly because of this; absolute rules are rare.

> 1. Use optional where we always return an empty optional, for this one implementation of getHeader()
> 2. Throw an exception, which will need to be caught to continue
> 3. Return an empty array for the header

(2) seems like a horrible idea.  Exceptions should be reserved for "if the program ends because of this, it is better than continuing", or similar.  Using them for control flow is a bad idea for many reasons.

(3) vs (1) depends on if an empty block of data is different than data that is missing.  Sometimes they are the same, sometimes not.  If they are the same, (1) is bad because you get 2 states that represent the same thing; if they are different then (3) is bad because you get one state that represents two things.